# How do you set a default focus() on an element

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, d3.js

I'm trying to make an Angular Application (uses D3.js) Web Accessible.

Goal: When a user calls for a particular chart (in this case a sunburst), the chart expands into view. My intention is to create a default focus on a specific element of the chart so once the user calls/selects the chart, the chart will automatically have focus.

Problem: Once I expand the sunburst chart into view, the Tabbing order resets from the start of the page (there is no page load as its a Single Page Application). Then the user would have to TAB through the whole page to navigate to the sunburst chart. 
I have already set the center node to have an attribute of *Tabindex:0*.
So now the center node can be accessed via keyboard navigation (tabbing).

```
var defaultNode = d3.select(sunburstChartdetail").select("path").attr("tabindex", 0);
```

I have tried:

```
  defaultNode.focus();
```

but I get a console error suggesting 'focus' is not a function

*NOTE: Unfortunately I cannot post the code for NDA reasons.*

Answer (score 1):

To focus on an element, you need to get a reference to the underlying DOM element:

```
d3.select("foobar").node().focus()
```

Or in your case:

```
defaultNode.node().focus()
```

[Documentation on `selection.node()`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#node)

Comment: Thanks @xbonez, I did try that initially,  but the focus is still not becoming the default. The tab order still resets to the the top of the page.